# I want to refer to a immutable variable outside of the function it is declared in

Tags: swift

I am very new to swift and am try to refer to my immutable variable `let button1 = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Bulky Pixels")` outside of the function it is declared in.

This is the function that the immutable variable is in:

```
func runMathsProblem(){
    currentGameState = gameSate.mathSlove

    if currentGameState == gameSate.mathSlove{
        self.speed = 0
    }

    let button1 = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Bulky Pixels")
    button1.name = "Button1"
    button1.text = "1"
    button1.fontSize = 110
    button1.fontColor = SKColor.white
    button1.zPosition = 120
    button1.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.3, y: self.size.height * 0.32)
    self.addChild(button1)
}
```

I want to be able to access button1 in the function:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)

        **//I want to refer to it like this**
        if button1.contains(pointOfTouch){
            self.speed = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to refer to it using the name I gave it?

I have tried looking into ways online but I am not sure whether I am looking up the right question.

I hope this is enough for you guys to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: Do some research on "variable scope".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare it outside the function like

```
var button1:SKLabelNode!
```

then

```
button1 = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Bulky Pixels")
```

but note you have to call `runMathsProblem` before any event inside `touchesMoved` or make it optional like

```
var button1:SKLabelNode?
```

Comment: I have been looking for an answer like this for a very long time, thanks!

Comment: Using implicitly unwrapped optionals in a situation like this seems ill-advised for a beginner. If you don't set the button variable then you'll crash.

Comment: @DuncanC it's not wrong to make the beginner get the difference between **?** and **!** even if it'll crash with him 1 time

Comment: Explaining how `!` works is not wrong, but using in sample code for a beginner does seem like a bad idea, unless you explain it in great detail, including the consequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Local variables are local, and only exist in the scope in which they are defined. If you define a variable inside a function, it only exists inside that function.

If you want the variable to be visible to other functions in the same object, make it an instance variable:

```
class MyClass {

     //Create an instance variable button1
     var button1: SKLabelNode?

     func runMathsProblem(){
         //Your code removed for brevity

         //This function now sets the instance variable rather than a local variable
         button1 = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Bulky Pixels")

         //Your code using Button1 removed for brevity
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches{
            let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)

            //Now this code works.
            if button1?.contains(pointOfTouch){
                self.speed = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if I add the "?" to `if button1?.contains(pointOfTouch)` I get the error `Value of optional type 'Bool?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Bool'`