# Unexpectedly found nil when using variable outside of declared function

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a kind of maths games where when an enemy is shot the user is prompted with a maths question, I made it so when an enemy is shot a keypad with numbers pops up where the user enters the answer. But whenever the keypad pops up I get the error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

At the top of the code I have declared the the variables I am using:

```
var button1:SKLabelNode?
var answerDisplay:SKLabelNode!
```

This is the function that runs when the enemy is shot:

```
func runMathsProblem(){
    //This is the label that is meant to display what the user enters

    let answerDisplay = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Bulky Pixels")
    answerDisplay.name = "AnswerDisplay"
    answerDisplay.text = "= "
    answerDisplay.fontSize = 110
    answerDisplay.fontColor = SKColor.white
    answerDisplay.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.left
    answerDisplay.zPosition = 110
    answerDisplay.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.38, y: self.size.height * 0.63)
    self.addChild(answerDisplay)

    //This is the button the user presses to type "1" on screen

    let button1 = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Bulky Pixels")
    button1.name = "Button1"
    button1.text = "1"
    button1.fontSize = 110
    button1.fontColor = SKColor.white
    button1.zPosition = 120
    button1.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.3, y: self.size.height * 0.32)
    self.addChild(button1)
}
```

This is where it detects if the user has pressed a button and is meant to to add the number pressed to the variable answerDisplay to display on screen(this is also where I get the error):

```
 override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)

        if button1!.contains(pointOfTouch){  **//This is where I get the error**
            answerDisplay!.text = answerDisplay.text! + "1"
        }
    }
}
```

I think it is something to do with the way I have declared the variable

Comment: Please carefully review the answers to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146457/i-want-to-refer-to-a-immutable-variable-outside-of-the-function-it-is-declared-i) and compare the code you posted here. You missed a subtle difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At the top of the code I have declared the the variables I am using

But you never end up using them, because...

```
let answerDisplay = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Bulky Pixels")
.
.
.
let button1 = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Bulky Pixels")
.
.
.
```

This creates **new instances** of `SKLabelNode` instead of using the ones you already created. So, what you need to do is remove the keyword `let` so that the compiler understands that you are referring to the variables that you already declared.

Comment: I somehow totally over looked that! I removed the let's yet I am still getting the same error though.

Comment: I have fixed it! Sorry I had changed something earlier but it hadn't saved that I changed it back. Thank you so much for your help.